# Tractive System Measuring Point

Tags: electric-vehicle, racing

What is meant by the term 'Measuring Points' when used in reference to the manufacturing of electric Formula Racing car. I [googled](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z-bmnDP4RZCYmEeWQcYcwzxPYoCNslzT/view?usp=sharing) and somehow got the sense that *measuring points* are certain terminals available from any electrical equipment to check whether its working or not by passing some voltage across these points. I know this is insanely raw or may be extremely wrong.

What does the term *Measuring Points* exactly mean? How to understand these points in terms of *Tractive System* of an Electric Formula vehicle?

I also [found](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AigGX-CNB-gvIqXdovCN0deBrrIb7yG5/view?usp=sharing) (EV 7.1.9) the use of these points present on the charger of an EV accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

"Measuring points" can be many things:

1. defined points on a chassis to check dimensions
2. defined points or pins provided on a circuit for measurement of voltages etc

So, unless we know what points exactly you refer to this has many answers.

Comment: Oops!  I read too quickly. My apologies.

Comment: @BillDOe been there, done exactly the same, no problem :)